# How to change a variable that is a char and represents a number into a float or int?

Tags: c++

A text file contains the next line " 1+2=4 ".I wanted to make a program that will read every char and store them in an array then change the char variebles that represent numbers into int type variables and then,based on the sign between the numbers and the number after the "=" , to output "Correct" or "Inccorect".
First I expected for the char variable that contained 1 to be turned in a int variable that  contained the value 1 but instead it contains 117. When I tried to look at an ASCII tabel 1 was 49. Is there a way to store the numbers directly into a int array,having the written value, and the signs into char array or some other way to overcome this problem ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything? Show some code that you wrote. :)  if you search around for "convert char to int" - you might find your solution, with a bit of work.  If your question remains the same, you will continue getting downvotes.

Comment: Yeah, we need to see what you've worked out by yourself, and we can help you with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some sort of iostream. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input("1+2=4");
    stringstream ss(input);

    int a, b, c;
    char sign;
    ss >> a >> sign >> b >> sign >> c;

    cout << (a + b == c) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Having converted your numbers using a stream, you can store them wherever you need.

Comment: Yeah, it will work only if you have "number sign number sign number". It's not really generic...

Comment: You can build a recursive descent parser using this technique as a building block if you want generality :)

Answer (score 0):

You should split the string and then use a library to parse the numbers.
For example you can use:

```
string input_number_string = "42.42";
float number;
sscanf(input_nuber_string, "%f", &number);
```

There are better libraries out there as well.

Comment: Where do you *split* the string?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews there are many methods to do it. Not knowing the context of the question makes it hard to choose between them, so I left it out of the code.